# Connecting to Cloud hosted MS Exchange APIs

Tags: api, rest, cloud, exchange-server

I'm trying to figure out how MS Exchange expose their cloud based APIs for use?

If they do, I'd like to use a HTTP connector to connect to them.

Any direction would be really helpful to a beginner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the getting started material: http://dev.office.com/getting-started.